# I'm using asterisk and asterisk-gui. But they are not conneciton

Tags: connection, asterisk

I'm using asterisk and asterisk-gui. But they are not conneciton.

I'm new to asterisk.

I run it on CentOs 6.5 and I'm using Asterisk 1.8.25.0.

I was set sip.conf, extensions.conf.

Calling, speaking and listening is no problem.

And, i was install Asterisk-GUI.

```
http://localhost:8088/asterisk/static/config/cfgbasic.html
```

This page is normally operates.

However, Asterisk and Asterisk-GUI is not connected.

My accounts are 108, 109.

But, don't show in Asterisk-GUI.

How to connect Asterisk, Asterisk-GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsteriskGUI is not supported anymore. User freepbx.org gui.

If you need AsteriskGUI(older unsupported version), you need be guru in javascript debugging. Except js issues, also can be issues with firewall or /etc/asterisk/manager.conf file.

Comment: Thank you. I will not using Asterisk-GUI.

I found a FreePBX that other Asterisk-GUI.